# how can a call a method on created_at when using it as a condition for a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make this query:

```
sector.posts.count(:conditions => {:created_at.month => 1..3})
```

However, it returns:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `month' for :created_at:Symbol

But if I do `post.created_at.month` in the console, it returns the integer value for the month. How would I accomplish the query that I am trying to make?

Comment: Something you're not thinking about is the fact when you write `:created_at` you are using a symbol. Symbol's don't have methods. Of course you can tell this from the error you received and I'm sure you're aware of it but I just wanted to reinforce that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the count method in this case. [More on sql conditions](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Conditions).

What you do is call the count method as so:

```
sector.posts.count(conditions: 'MONTH(created_at) in (1,2,3)')
```

or a better way of doing this:

```
sector.posts.where('MONTH(created_at) in (1,2,3)').count
```

Comment: I like the idea of putting the processing load on the database itself if the month method is supported. Mysql has this method while Postgresql does not (or at least it is not called MONTH).

Comment: Needs to be "sector.posts.where('MONTH(posts.created_at) in (1,2,3)').count" to avoid ambiguity for created_at, other than that it works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to call a method on the symbol :created_at in your query. In your console example, you are calling the method against an ActiveRecord object.

If you are trying to get the results from within a date range, use a BETWEEN query (at least on [Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) or [Postresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-comparison.html)) and set the beginning and end dates for the range.

```
sector.posts.where(["'posts.created_at' BETWEEN ? AND ?", Date.new(2013,1,1), Date.new(2013,3,31)])
```

You can also use the beginning_of date methods, such as [beginning_of_quarter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-beginning_of_quarter) if you need your queries to be dynamic. They're pretty powerful.